# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSuggestionsAllowed() on null

Tags: magento2, theme, fatal-error

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSuggestionsAllowed() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magx/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml:27 on line 27`

I have installed a new theme in **Magento 2.3.6** which is
https://www.hiddentechies.com/etrend-lite-free-magento-2-theme.html

But when i install this theme and applying on frontend i am getting this error.
Here is my `form.mini.phtml`.

```
    <?php $helper = $this->helper(\Magento\Search\Helper\Data::class);
$configProvider = $block->getData('configProvider');
?>

div class="block block-search">
    <div class="block block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block block-content">
        <form class="form minisearch" id="search_mini_form"
              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($helper->getResultUrl()) ?>" method="get">
            <div class="field search">
                <label class="label" for="search" data-role="minisearch-label">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input id="search"
                            <?php if ($configProvider->isSuggestionsAllowed()):?>
                               data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
                                    "formSelector":"#search_mini_form",
                                    "url":"<?= $block->escapeUrl($helper->getSuggestUrl())?>",
                                    "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete",
                                    "minSearchLength":"<?= $block->escapeHtml($helper->getMinQueryLength()) ?>"}
                               }'
                            <?php endif;?>
                           type="text"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getQueryParamName()) ?>"
                           value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $helper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>"
                           placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Search entire store here...')) ?>"
                           class="input-text"
                           maxlength="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getMaxQueryLength()) ?>"
                           role="combobox"
                           aria-haspopup="false"
                           aria-autocomplete="both"
                           autocomplete="off"
                           aria-expanded="false"/>
                    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Search')) ?>"
                    class="action search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                >
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to get $configProvider value from helper class?

Comment: here is my config provider function
 public function isSuggestionsAllowed(): bool
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::SEARCH_SUGGESTION_ENABLED,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

Comment: are you sure you're calling the right helper at `<?php $helper = $this->helper(\Magento\Search\Helper\Data::class);`?

Comment: i have same problem, with my Magento 2.3.6 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/chroot/home/ae...', Array)
#4 /ch in /chroot/home/aec8be3d/b4115eb564.nxcli.io/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml on line 27

Answer (score 1):

what php version you that used ?
You should run setup:upgrade and di compilation first, after that run static deploy. If that way not work try switch back your enviroment to default magento 2 theme for check problem. If problem not happen this maybe root cause issue come from custom theme

**Updated**
Another possible is block name `top.search` was removed somewhere in theme or custom modules

Comment: 2.3.6 is my magento version

Comment: i already know that in your description but you don't mention php version! maybe wrong php version could cause issue

Comment: My php version is 7.3

Comment: Have you check updated note above in my answer

Comment: I also get this error on luma theme.